# Getting Revmob banner listener to work in Corona

Tags: lua, listener, coronasdk, banner, revmob

I am trying to get the banner listener to work in corona so I will be able to know if a user has touched my ad. The first listener works (for the session) but the banner one never returns anything. Any ideas will help. I have been working on this for at least a day now. and I am currently using revmob.lua.

Here is what I have so far:

```
-- This is Objects.revmob because I have my revmob.lua folder inside my Objects folder
local RevMob = require "Objects.revmob" 
local REVMOB_IDS =  {["Android"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
local PLACEMENT_IDS = {["Android"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}


-- Set up ad listener.
local function adListener( event )
RevMob.setTestingMode(RevMob.TEST_WITH_ADS)
function revmobListener(event)
        print("Event: " .. event.type .. " - " .. event.ad)
end
revMobBanner = RevMob.createBanner({listener = revmobListener }, PLACEMENT_IDS)
    if(event.isError) then
        print("There was an error")
    end
    if(event.response ~= nil) then
        print(event.response)
    end
end

RevMob.startSessionWithListener(REVMOB_IDS, adListener)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who needs the answer to this question. I was able to contact Revmob and get help on this issue. Turns out it was a bug in the revmob.lua SDK 5.5.1 Download the new one from http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/corona.html#download 
Happy coding everyone!